# Downloading data from a shared google drive link in google colab

Tags: download, html-lists, google-colaboratory, drive

I want to download data from google drive link shared by someone using google colab. I am a new user of colab and I don't know how to do that.
the links are

x_train: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cUaIEd9-MLJHFGjLz5QziNvfBtYygplX

y_train: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hv24Ufiio9rBeSqgnNoM3dr5sVGwOmBy

x_test: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AH9lKHT5P2oQLz8SGMRPWs_M9wIM2ZRH

y_test: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i4_azocSDuU3TcDf3OSHO1vF0D5-xMU6

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done or not (maybe others can weigh in), but what I usually do is to add the files to my own Google Drive or GitHub and get them from there.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `gdown` if the file is shared publicly.

```
!gdown 1cUaIEd9-MLJHFGjLz5QziNvfBtYygplX
```

If it's shared to you only, you need to use pydrive

```py
# Install the PyDrive wrapper & import libraries.
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file_id = '1cUaIEd9-MLJHFGjLz5QziNvfBtYygplX'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':file_id})
downloaded.FetchMetadata(fetch_all=True)
downloaded.GetContentFile(downloaded.metadata['title'])
```

If they share a folder, it's too long so I made it short in my library.

```py
!pip install kora
from kora import drive
drive.download_folder('1HvIeNhqtFVllXFWzH5NawDdnIfgGDwCK')
```

Comment: I tried to download a folder with your library but it is asking for a verification code. What code does that mean? Is it possible to specify it in code so I don't have to type it at console prompt?

Comment: @korakot I'm getting an error with kora at your "import download" line in drive.py:                     
----> 3 drive.download_folder('1HvIeNhqtFVllXFWzH5NawDdnIfgGDwCK')
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kora/drive.py in download_folder(folder_id)
     60     urlretrieve(url, path)
     61     # recursive download
---> 62     import download
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'download'

Answer (score 9):

A great question and something that I have been working with for some time. The most seamless/ workflow friendly is using [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown).

[image]
 
Presently Colab has a slightly older version install which does not allow full functionality and is installed on pyton2.7 rather than Colab system python. therefore following the terminal/underlining os via `!` method, `!pip installing`:

```py
!pip uninstall gdown -y && pip install gdown
!gdown -V
```

Then you can use gdown via another `!` **(method 1)** or import gdown **(method 2)** if you want to use it in code:

> **Method 1** for whole shared folders/directories:

```py
!gdown --folder https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/sdsldkfj...somefileid.. -O /some_parent_directory/some_child_directory
```

for files:

```py
!gdown https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/sdsldkfj...somefileid.. -O /some_parent_directory/some_child_directory
```

> **Method 2** Using down via importing works as follows:

```py
import gdown
url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B9P1L--7Wd2vNm9zMTJWOGxobkU'
output = '20150428_collected_images.tgz'
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
```

Pasting your google drive file/directory url in both cases.

Hope this helps <^_^>

Answer (score 1):

If you have a link to someone's publicly shared file on Google Drive, you can do this in *4 mouse clicks*:

1. Create a shortcut to this file in your Google Drive (right-click *on file* -> *"Add shortcut to Disk"*)
2. Mount your Google drive in Colab notebook (click buttons: *"Files"* -> *"Mount Drive"*)
3. Now you can access this file via your shortcut for `!unzip/np.load/`...